# stripe out part of url via modrewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, silverstripe

i've got the following url construction from my cms

```
domain.de/cmsfolder/page1/page2/function/my-news-headline
```

or

```
domain.de/cmsfolder/page1/function/my-reference-headline
```

i want to stripe out the function so that my url is

```
domain.de/cmsfolder/page1/page2/my-news-headline
```

or

```
domain.de/cmsfolder/page1/my-reference-headline
```

and didn't result in an 404 error.

can someone tell me if this is possible and how?

or perhaps it is possible to stripe out "function" out of any url of my page?

Best regards and thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

not an elegant solution, but this will work in case you only got 1 action ('myfunction') in your pages controller:

add this to `Page_Controller`:

```
private $actionName;

private static $allowed_actions = array (
    'myfunction'
);

static $url_handlers = array(
    '' => 'myfunction'
);

public function init(){
    parent::init();

    $urlParams = $this->getURLParams();
    if(isset($urlParams['Action'])) { //might not be set when coming from '/' or '/home'
        $this->actionName = $urlParams['Action'];
    }
}

public function myfunction() {
    //do something here with $this->actionName
}
```

now, when you navigate to `domain.de/cmsfolder/page1/page2/my-news-headline`, `$actionName` will be set to 'my-news-headline', and `myfunction` is called to work with it.

Comment: thank you but i do not understand what to do with $actionName and ['Action']. Leave it like it is? My function is "show" from the DataObjectasPages Module http://www.sspaste.com/paste/show/52975688ee774